# Parent with overflow-x: hidden hides vertically translated child

Tags: css

Let's say I want to hide container's horizontal content, but at the same time time I want to translate child elements. Adding `overflow-x: hidden;` to the parent causes it to clip vertically translated children too. Why does this happen and how can I work around it?

```css
.content{
  margin: 1rem;
}

.rail {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: #EEE;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.card {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: #FFF;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: translate3d(0px, -1.5rem, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="rail">
    <div class="card">CONTENT</div>
  </div>
</div
```

Comment: Sadly this is a problem i faced for many weeks with carousels before, setting the overflow behavior of an element changes it into a `scroll container`, even setting it to `clip` which doesn't create a new `scroll container` doesn't produce desirable behavior. as per the spec definition.
The best i could do was increase the height of the element as to not clip the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similiar issue recently as well, a workaround I found was just to wrap a new container around the transformed element:

```css
.content {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.rail {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: #EEE;
}

.card {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: #FFF;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: translate3d(0px, -1.5rem, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="rail">
    <div class="card-container">
      <div class="card">CONTENT</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just need to ask why this was accepted when it appears to not address the problem, ie, it does not have the required(?) overflow- x in the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, yes you have to make the rail higher.

However, you can do this and make it look like it is not bigger.  See the following CSS:

```
.content{
    margin: 1rem;

    /*  Just to help show what is happening  */
    padding: 1rem;
    background: pink;

    /*  Parameterise the work around  */
    --railPadding: 0.5rem;
    --vertTranslate: -1.5rem;
    --extraSpace: calc(0px - (var(--railPadding) + var(--vertTranslate)));
}

.rail {

    /*  The important constraints.  */
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: hidden;

    /*  Make the extra space without changing the content box of the rail.  */
    padding: calc(var(--railPadding) + var(--extraSpace)) var(--railPadding) var(--railPadding) var(--railPadding);
    /*  Offset the extra height by backing over the margin.  */
    margin-top: calc(0px - var(--extraSpace));
    /*  Make the rail look like it has not backed over anything by making the overlap transparent.  */
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #EEE calc(100% - var(--extraSpace)), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) var(--extraSpace));
}

.card {
    padding: 1.0rem;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background: #FFF;
}

.card:hover {
    transform: translate3d(0px, var(--vertTranslate), 0px);
}
```